# UITableView crashes at start at tableview.datasource

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, viewcontroller

I have implemented two UITableview in seperate ViewController classes. After successfully adding the code for the second UItableView my project builds but stops after loading.

It stops with a red line on:

```
tableView.delegate.dataSource = self
```

With an error that reads:

> Thread 1 EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code-EXC_i386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

AND

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Since this didn't happen until adding the second UItableview in the second view controller I'm wondering if maybe my code is conflicting with each other. I will post copies of both view controllers. What should I change?

By the way: FilmsViewController is where the app is crashing. Although it was working prior to adding MCViewController Films:

**B:**

```
class FilmsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var tableView : UITableView!
    var FilmArray = [String]()

    let film_url = "https://www.testing.com/api/resources/films/1"
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return FilmArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell", for:indexPath) as! FilmsAPITableViewCell
        // Configuring Cell
        cell.movieTitle.text = FilmArray[indexPath.row]
        // Returning the cell
        return cell
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        let url:URL = URL(string: film_url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("740c94c51891c02b64d6c78840b478fe0b02fe2c", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
        request.setValue("Basic YmhlZW0uZW5nckBnbWFpbC5jb206YmgzM20=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        let paramString = ""

        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                return
            }



            var json:Any?

            do
            {
                if let existingData = data {
                    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: existingData, options: [])
                }

                //  Prasing JSON
                if let parsedData = json as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for dict in parsedData {
                        if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
                            self.FilmArray.append(title)
                            print(json)
                        }
                    }

                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }

            if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
                {
                    //  self.login_session = session_data

                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                    //  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

**MC:**

```
   class MCViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let message_url = "https://www.testing.com/api/resources/get_film_message/film_id/3825"
    let send_url = "https://www.testing.com/api/resources/send_film_message"
    let film_id = "3825"
    var messageArray = [String]()
    weak var tableView : UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messageArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "msgContent", for:indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell
        // Configuring Cell
        cell.msgContent.text = messageArray[indexPath.row]
        // Returning the cell
        return cell
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var MessageInput: UITextField!
    @IBAction func Sendmsg(_ sender: Any) {
        Sendmsg(username:MessageInput.text!, password: film_id)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


        //        post_data.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
        //        post_data.setValue(password, forKey: "password")

        let url:URL = URL(string: message_url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("740c94c51891c02b64d6c78840b478fe0b02fe2c", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
        request.setValue("Basic YmhlZW0uZW5nckBnbWFpbC5jb206YmgzM20=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        var paramString = ""


        //        for (key, value) in post_data
        //        {
        //            paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
        //        }
        //
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                return
            }



            let json: Any?

            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                if let parsedData = json as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for dict in parsedData {
                        if let title = dict["message"] as? String {
                            self.messageArray.append(title)
                            print(json)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }


            if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
                {
                    //  self.login_session = session_data

                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                    //  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)
                }
            }



        })

        task.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func Sendmsg(username:String, password:String)
    {
        let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


        post_data.setValue(username, forKey: "message")
        post_data.setValue(password, forKey: "film_id")

        let url:URL = URL(string: send_url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("740c94c51891c02b64d6c78840b478fe0b02fe2c", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
        request.setValue("Basic YmhlZW0uZW5nckBnbWFpbC5jb206YmgzM20=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        var paramString = ""


        for (key, value) in post_data
        {
            paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
        }

        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                return
            }



            let json: Any?

            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print(json)
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }


//            if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
//            {
//                if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
//                {
//                    self.login_session = session_data
//                    
//                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
//                    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")
//                    
//                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)
//                }
//            }
//            


        })

        task.resume()


    }


    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing `tableView`? Seems like it might be `nil`....

`tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)`

If you're using storyboard/xib, you can also hook `tableView` up as an [IBOutlet](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html).

Comment: tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)? I'm not sure I am calling it. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: where should i call it?

Comment: I would call it in `viewDidLoad`, before doing anything else. The `frame` argument would be a `CGRect` with x,y position and width, height that you want. Though I would be careful setting frames based on the view's frame in `viewDidLoad` as the view's frame isn't calculated yet. `tableView = UITableView()` in `viewDidLoad` and then `tableView.frame = CGRect(x: yourX, y: yourY, width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)` elsewhere like in `viewDidAppear` could also be a viable option.

Comment: i didnt have that before and it worked when just using one. Is there a reason why i should add this now if it were working before?

Comment: From the code above it looks like you have two different classes with the same name in the same project? I have to admit I'm a bit baffled as to how that would even compile, as well as how a table view could work without being initialized somehow.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out it was actually a mistake. The classes are different.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm still confused about where the table view is given a value. Is it hooked up to something in a storyboard or .xib file?

Comment: I fixed by using storyboard and IBOutlet for tableview